# Send DNS data: MSB or LSB first?

Tags: dns, protocols, communication, network-protocols, endianness

I'm implementing a DNS(multicast DNS in fact) in c#.

I just want to know if I must encode my uint/int/ushort/... with the LSB on the left or the MSB on the left. And more globally how I could know this? One of this is standard?

Because I didn't found anything in the IETF description. I found a lot of things(each header field length, position), but I didn't found this.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you read RFC 1035 (2.3.2. Data Transmission Order) ?

Comment: @oleg_g : Nope I didn't, so the MSB is on the left. I just have to find which encoding is using the c# BinaryWriter now :). Can you post your comment as answer? Like this I can accept that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in RFC 1035 (2.3.2. Data Transmission Order)

Here is the link: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt

And the interesting part

> 2.3.2. Data Transmission Order
>
> The order of transmission of the header and data described in this
>   document is resolved to the octet level.  Whenever a diagram shows a 
>   group of octets, the order of transmission of those octets is the
>   normal order in which they are read in English.  For example, in the
>   following diagram, the octets are transmitted in the order they are
>   numbered.
>
> ```
>  0                   1
>  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |       1       |       2       |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |       3       |       4       |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |       5       |       6       |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> ```
>
> Whenever an octet represents a numeric quantity, the left most bit in
>   the diagram is the high order or most significant bit.  That is, the
>   bit labeled 0 is the most significant bit.  For example, the following
>   diagram represents the value 170 (decimal).
>
> ```
>  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0|
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> ```
>
> Similarly, whenever a multi-octet field represents a numeric quantity
>   the left most bit of the whole field is the most significant bit. 
>   When a multi-octet quantity is transmitted the most significant octet
>   is transmitted first.